# перенаправление при помощи htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Есть проблема, помогите пожалуйста решить.
Для открытия товаров в интернет магазине есть файл viewtovar.php в файле htaccess он переименовывается в catalog вот такой командой

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9\-]+)?$ viewtovar.php?id=$1 [L]
```

но если создать в корне сайта файл catalog.php все перестает работать, и товары не открываются и страница catalog.php тоже не открывается. Как это починить? :)

Answer (score 0):

Никак не исправите - это виртуальный файл/каталог, и обычно есть еще в htaccess такая примерная базовая конструкция:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]
```

То есть - ЕСЛИ нет реальной папки или реального файла, то...

На виртуальный папках обычно строятся и языковые версии - на самом деле папок нет, они есть только в uri и в виртуале как метки переключения языков...

Поэтому, когда Вы создаете реальную папку/файл, то вся логика рушится.

А вообще - виртуализация великая вещь в силу динамичности и невероятной гибкости для создания виртуализированных динамических надстроек и структур.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, а как тогда у других интернет магазинов работают оба пути `http://mysite.com/catalog` и `http://mysite.com/catalog/phone-nokia3310` ?

Comment: Пожалуйста) А как вы проверяете, есть ли они в реале или нет? А если и есть, то приведенные вами ссылки разные - потому, обработка может быть индивидуализирована - например, просто catalog не будет работать, а именно catalog/xnj-то там - будет, благодаря инструкциям и настройкам.
Ну, и в каждом случае нужно смотреть - потому как все в деталях, несмотря на кажущееся внешнее сходство. В любом случае есть логика работы приложения/частей/элементов - вот от нее и нужно оттталкиваться - вплоть до распределенного хранения данных на разных серверах в единой структуре.